# The host path of the shared folder is missing: path/to/file Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, laravel-5, homestead

I keep getting this error while runing : `vagrant up` :

[image]

**Homestead.yaml**

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Applications/MAMP/htdocs
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/aveniros/Laravel/public
```

Can someone please point out what I did wrong here ?

Comment: Replace the tilde (`~`) by the full path of the home directory? (which seems to be `/home/vagrant`)

Comment: Care to explain the downvote !! so I can learn from it.

Comment: I'm guessing (I didn't downvote) that it's because the question isn't really programming-related.

Comment: For people that downvote without explain your reason to OP, you guys are disrespect others, bully, one simple word for you is **ignorance**.

Comment: According to my tags, they're obviously not a programming related. If they're not allow this kind of question why those tags are **exist**.  My post is clean, short, and simple, showing my goal, what I've tried, and also what I expect to see. I'm stuck.. so what... I'm sure at some point , some people that use a Mac and tried to set up Homestead will be beneficial from this post.

Comment: @rangerover.js similar to what robertklep mentioned, it was probably down-voted because not strictly programming-related and perhaps a better fit for Serverfault. However, Vagrant questions are still popular here because it's primarily a developer tool rather than a "server" per se. (Compare questions tagged with 'vagrant': about 3100 on Stackoverflow and 290 in Serverfault.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix this disaster by by deleting the (`~`)

**Homestead.yaml**

```
folders:
- map: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code 
  to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/code/aveniros/Laravel/public
```

It should work now.

[image]

Then, if you open up your `Virtual Box` Application, you should see something like this :

[image]

Hope this answer help ! :D